# How navigate from viewcontroller.swift file to corresponding scene in *.storyboard file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way (key combination, context menu) in Xcode to quickly navigate from a custom UIViewController (`AViewController.swift` for example) file to a screen in the storyboard, which has `AViewController.swift` shown as a custom class in the Identity inspector tab?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a storyboard id in identity inspector in storyboard. Then push with:

```
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

identifier is the storyboard id

Or you can present it with:

```
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```